# Too young to marry each other or get married

Tags: phrase-choice

Which of the following sentences is correct?

> I think the couple are too young to marry each other.

> I think the couple are too young to get married to each other.

I know it's wrong to say "the film is too boring to watch it."

Comment: Remove the redundancy; 'the couple' forces a 'to each other' reading. << (A') I think the couple are too young to marry. // 

(B') I think the couple are too young to get married. >>

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence

> the film is too boring to watch it

is problematic because if you replace the pronoun (it) with the content (the film), it becomes (is equivalent to):

> the film is too boring to watch the film

Then, a film cannot watch itself.

But a couple can marry each other, or get married to each other. So the above problem does not apply.

Comment: But adding 'each other' is unnecessary. If they are described as 'a couple', it's clear that the potential marriage would be between them.

Comment: @KateBunting I agree that `with each other` can be implied.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "couple" as a plural word you are referring to two individual people who are linked. With this understanding both sentences are correct.

Alternatively you could have used "couple" as a singular word, as in

> I think the couple is too young to marry.

or

> I think the couple is too young to get married.

In this case "couple" means a set of two people (in mathematical terms one set with two elements). The couple marries when its members marry each other, and adding "each other" to the last two sentences would be incorrect.

Comment: This answer may work for the UK but not for the US.

Answer (score 0):

You want to refer to the two people *as two individuals*. The word "couple" refers to them *collectively*, and therefore does not suit your purpose. So you could say
"I think they are too young to marry each other." or "I think they are too young to get married to each other."